# Quant Trading Robot #1 - API Calls

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm (re)building a Quantitative Trading Robot in Python.

---

Description:

This is my module for API Calls. The API documentation can be found [here](https://docs.gdax.com/). This is the direct interface layer between my code and the exchange server. Any abstraction on top of the direct API calls is in a separate module.

Classes:

`GDAXExchangeAuth` - Authentication for restricted API Calls

Functions:

`get_server_time` - Retrieve the curent server time

`get_account` - Retrieve Account balances

`get_book` - Retrieve the order book for a specified currency pair

`get_fills_after_order` - Retrieve all filled orders that have occurred after some specific order id.

`post_limit_order` - Post an order to the exchange

`get_price_history` - Retrieve the price history for a specific currency pair

---

Areas of interest:

The usual, am I following conventions, how's my naming, how's my documentation, how well thought-out is my structure?

---

```
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import requests
import base64
from requests.auth import AuthBase

API_KEY = 'redacted'
API_SECRET = 'redacted'
API_PASSPHRASE = 'redacted'
API_URL = 'https://api.gdax.com/'


class GDAXExchangeAuth(AuthBase):
    SIGNATURE_HTTP_HEADER = 'CB-ACCESS-SIGN'
    TIMESTAMP_HTTP_HEADER = 'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'
    KEY_HTTP_HEADER = 'CB-ACCESS-KEY'
    PASSPHRASE_HTTP_HEADER = 'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE'

    def __init__(self, api_key, secret_key, passphrase, server_time):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.secret_key = secret_key
        self.passphrase = passphrase
        self.server_time = server_time

    def __call__(self, request):
        epoch = self.server_time['epoch']
        timestamp = str(epoch)
        request.headers.update(
            {
                'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
                'CB-ACCESS-KEY': self.api_key,
                'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': self.passphrase,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        )

        message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url + (request.body or '')
        message = message.encode()
        hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key)
        signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message, hashlib.sha256)
        signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(signature.digest())

        request.headers.update(
            {
                'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature_b64,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        )

        return request


def get_server_time():
    url = API_URL + 'time'
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r


def get_account(server_time):
    auth = GDAXExchangeAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET, API_PASSPHRASE, server_time)
    url = API_URL + 'accounts'
    r = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
    return r


def get_book(product, level):
    # level 1 = Bid/Ask
    url = API_URL + '/products/' + product + '/book?level=' + str(level)
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r


def get_fills_after_order(server_time, order_id):
    # get all filled orders after the order id.
    # max 100 results returned
    auth = GDAXExchangeAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET, API_PASSPHRASE, server_time)
    url = API_URL + 'fills?before=' + str(order_id)
    r = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
    return r


def post_limit_order(server_time, side, price, size, product_id):
    order_type = 'limit'

    order = {}
    order['side'] = side
    order['price'] = price
    order['size'] = size
    order['product_id'] = product_id
    order['type'] = order_type

    auth = GDAXExchangeAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET, API_PASSPHRASE, server_time)
    url = API_URL + 'orders'
    data = json.dumps(order)
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, auth=auth)
    return r


def get_price_history(product_id, start, end, granularity):
    params = {}
    params['start'] = start
    params['end'] = end
    params['granularity'] = granularity

    url = API_URL + '/products/' + product_id + '/candles'
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    return r
```

Answer (score 5):

To check your code against coding standard and some error detection, I'd suggest you pylint, if you don't know it already.
Running pylint on your original code gives a list of things to check and a score 7.29/10 which is a good start.

What you should fix:

- add docstrings at module, class and function level.
- remove temporary variables when used just once.

  ```
  r = requests.get(url, params=params)
  return r

  return requests.get(url, params=params)
  ```
- prefer string formatting over concatenation.

  ```
  url = API_URL + '/products/' + product_id + '/candles'
  url = '%s/products/%s/candles' % (API_URL, product_id)
  ```
- no need to initialize each dictionary's key separately.

  ```
  order = {}
  order['side'] = side
  order['price'] = price
  order['size'] = size
  order['product_id'] = product_id
  order['type'] = order_type

  order = {
      'side': side,
      'price': price,
      'size': size,
      'product_id': product_id,
      'type': order_type
  }
  ```
- consider parameter injection for the GDAXExchangeAuth instance in all your functions, it will simplify testing or reusing of the code with a different Authentication method.

Pylint complains about GDAXExchangeAuth class having too few public methods, but in this case I like the usage of a function class and there is no real need of other methods, so for me it's fine.

I assume this is probably just an example, but in any case I suggest also getting sensitive information from environment variables, something like

```
    import os

    API_PASSPHRASE = os.environ['API_PASSPHRASE']
```

Comment: Python Docs kinda [recommend against using `%` formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

Comment: Not in favor of string concatenation. String literals may actually improve readability, but they still use % operator

Comment: When did I say I was in favour of that. `str.format` or f-strings are what the docs, I linked to, recommend.

Comment: When did I say you were :D .format is the new way, you're right, my suggestion was to use string formatting, not specifically %, which will be always supported anyway.
I think .format is overkill here, but I can change the response.